# Dell XPS 12 and Ubuntu 13.10 Touchpad/Screen Woes

Tags: dell, touchpad, 13.10, touchscreen

I have read all the links and posts. Slapping 13.10 onto this XPS 12 convertible runs everything fine out of the box, bar some things.

1. Touchpad (no multitouch/scrolling) - Sputnik only supports up to 12.10 and all changes are supposed to have been integrated. No touchpad option shows up in settings
2. Touchscreen is supported but only as a pointer, i.e. not able to scroll in chrome etc
3. Screen rotation (least important, but no switching when the button is pressed).

I am not looking for handouts, or step by steps, but I was wondering if someone has had any experience with these issues?

Thanks!

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 you can scroll with touchpad (double fingers).

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your kernel is up to date - I'm on 3.11 at the moment.

Have you installed any multitouch apps? A good one to try is planarity. If that works with multiple touches, you know whether its your setup or a problem with the hardware.

If you want gestures there are 2 options - ginn and touchegg. I'm using touchegg on my XPS12 at the moment, but thats because I'm on Gnome Shell.

Overall it seems like there is relatively little out there about running a touch screen in linux, but the Arch wiki is pretty good for tips. IIRC your laptop will be using an Atmel maXTouch Digitizer. You may have more luck finding stuff relating to the actual hardware component, as opposed to just a laptop model.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_Thinkpad_Helix

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchscreen

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same problems, on a Dell XPS 12 9Q33 running Xubuntu 13.10

I installed `touchegg` using:

`$ sudo apt-get install touchegg`

but nothing seemed to work in the program.

What was really odd was that when I tried to compile the `touchegg` gui from source:

https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce

it wouldn't work...gave me a weird make error, something to to tune of: `

Make: No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/mkspecs/de Make Stop`

Researching more, at least for, looks like it may be an upstream bug...because the system recognizes my touchscreen, the computer also thinks the touch pad is a normal touchpad, not a synaptics one

http://libcoding.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/issue-with-touchpad-in-ubuntu-13-10-in-xps-12/comment-page-1/#comment-22

Apparently the workaround is blacklisting the `i2c_hid` module , which the dude explains how to do.

But yeah, this is frustrating.

OP, I see you asked this 5 months ago, did you figure anything out?

Comment: Nothing figured out thus far. I am still having the same troubles. I mainly use this as a desktop so the touchscreen is a minor issue for me, but the touchpad thing does suck.

Comment: well, black listing the i2c_hid module does work as a work-around; only thing is the touchscreen will no longer register the input, but it seems like that won't be a big deal for you.

Comment: Yep, have done that. Will be nice when a proper fix is in place but I appreciate that the problem is niche and there are more important things to work on. Thanks for giving an update, though!!